# Are there any state-level data on US banking regulation stringency?

Tags: banking, data-request, united-states, regulation

In  [Barth, Caprio, and Levine (2008) Rethinking bank regulation: Till angels govern. Cambridge University Press](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/rethinking-bank-regulation/1F17D4B8126212E2E6D5D11875F1FCF0), authors assemble and showcase large dataset on stringency of banking regulation and barriers on entry into banking industry across the world. This data included index of entry barriers (based on number of denied applications), capital stringency index (based on stringency of capital regulations), restriction on bank activities index and so on.

My question is, is there a comparable dataset for U.S. on state level?

Note, the data and indices do not have  to use exactly the same measure or constructed in exactly the same way. I am looking just for some dataset that would provide some indication on how large entry barriers are across different states, and some measure of how strict per-period banking regulation is in order to have some gauge of any state-level heterogeneity in this area).

Comment: If you find it hard to have an answer here, you can post to "Politics"(https://politics.stackexchange.com/) or "Open Data" (https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) exchanges for help

Comment: @NoviceMindset thanks but on politics.se this would be off topic and open data stack recommends in their help center to submit data requests to specialized stacks even if they are welcomed there as well

Comment: Current stringency or historical? To my knowledge, currently there isn't much variation at the state level.

Comment: @BKay both are good. Also I know there isn’t much variation but I would expect at least some like on 10 point scale maybe variation between 7-8 across states

Comment: I think the most substantial regulatory differences can get in the last 50 years or so will be the interstate and branch banking deregulation (discussed in numerous papers but see for example BECK, LEVINE, LEVKOV (JF 2010)). My problem in writing this up as an answer for you is that reregulation of branch banking isn't necessarily a change in strictness, because branching allows for diversification which is stabilizing. If you want to know about entry barriers, how about looking at new bank charters per capita or as a fraction of current bank charters?

Comment: @BKay no branch banking deregulation is not what I am interested in, new bank chapters per capita would work, I could just reconstruct their index using that but I was sort of hoping there is some data already out there and I am just not able to locate it because maybe the dataset has some weird name or is part of a book or paper like the data from Barth et al